# How to (sort of) control android device from webapp?

Tags: android, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to be able to control Android phone through my webapp. I need to know which permissions do I need to take from user from his/her google account. For example I need another user to be able to send an address to this user and this should open his Google Map with that address shown. Or send a message and it should be somehow opened on the user's phone. Is this all possible? If yes, then how. If no, what can be the closest we can achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If your are creating an Android application that can be installed on users phone than as far as I know this is quite possible...
All you need to do is to use push notifications server like firebase to send the data from your webapp to an application on users phone. Then according to the request received the application has to determine which intent/Broadcast to send.